# How to discretize or transform an optimal control problem with free final time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, control-theory, optimal-control

Given is the following simple optimal control problem:

$$
\begin{align}
&\min_{x, u, t_f} t_f  \\ %
\text{s.t.} \qquad \dot{x}(t) &= \begin{pmatrix} x_2(t) \\ u(t) \end{pmatrix} \\%
x(0) &= (0, 0)^{\top} \\
x(t_f) &= (300, 0)^{\top} \\
x_1(t) &\in [0, 33] \\
x_2(t) &\in [0, 330] \\
u(t) &\in [-2, 1]
\end{align}
$$

with $x(t) = (x_1(t), x_2(t))^\top$. Here, $t_f$ is the free final time. I'd like to discretize the problem and solve it with a NLP solver. However, how can I handle the $t_f$ variable when discretizing the problem? Is there some transformation technique for the problem?

Comment: The constraints don't make sense. Namely, the first state looks like a position and the second state as a velocity, the position starts at 0 and should end at 300 but should remain between 0 and 33. Did you maybe switch the state constraints?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks for your comment. The problem is cited from [here](https://mintoc.de/index.php/Time_optimal_car_problem). My real problem is more complex, so I picked the smallest similar problem I could find. The crucial question for me is how to discretize the problem, since the free final time $t_f$ is also a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's handle the general case with free initial and free final time:

$$
\begin{align}
&\min_{x, u, t_0, t_f} &\quad& \varphi(t_0, t_f, x(t_0), x(t_f)) \\
&\text{s.t.} & \dot{x}(t) &= f(t, x(t), u(t)) \\
&& 0 &= h(t_0, t_f, x(t_0), x(t_f)) \\
&& u(t) &\in \mathcal{U}
\end{align}
$$

Here, $x$ is the state, $u$ the control, $f$ the ODE rhs and $h$ are the boundary conditions. The basic idea is now to map the interval $[0, 1]$ onto the interval $[t_0,t_f]$. For this purpose we introduce the linear time transformation
$$
t(\tau) := t_0 + \tau \cdot (t_f - t_0), \quad \tau \in [0, 1]
$$
and define
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{x}(\tau) := x(t(\tau)) = x(t_0 + \tau \cdot (t_f - t_0)), \\
\overline{u}(\tau) := u(t(\tau)) = u(t_0 + \tau \cdot (t_f - t_0)).
\end{align}
$$

Then, we have by the chain rule:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d \tau} \overline{x}({\tau}) = t'(\tau) \cdot \dot{x}(t(\tau))
&= (t_f - t_0) \cdot f(t(\tau), x(t(\tau)), u(t(\tau))) \\
&= (t_f - t_0) \cdot f(t(\tau), \overline{x}(\tau), \overline{u}(\tau)).
\end{align}
$$

By interpreting $t_0$ and $t_f$ as constant states where the initial values $t_0(0)$ and $t_f(0)$ are free, we obtain the optimal control problem:

$$
\begin{align}
&\min_{x, u, t_0, t_f} &\quad& \varphi(t_0(0), t_f(1), \overline{x}(0), \overline{x}(1)) \\
%
&\text{s.t.} & \frac{d}{d \tau}\overline{x}(\tau) &= (t_0(\tau) - t_f(\tau) ) \cdot f(t(\tau), \overline{x}(\tau), \overline{u}(\tau)) \\
%
&& \frac{d}{d \tau} t_0(\tau) &= 0 \\
&& \frac{d}{d \tau} t_f(\tau) &= 0 \\
&& 0 &= h(t_0(0), t_f(1), \overline{x}(0), \overline{x}(1)) \\
&& \overline{u}(\tau) &\in \mathcal{U}
\end{align}
$$

This problem can easily be discretized for $\tau$.

A reference for this transformation technique is chapter 1.2.1 of [Optimal Control of ODEs and DAEs (Gerdts, M.)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110249996/html).